Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build
I am not sure what I'm doing wrong
enter image description here
activity_main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--suppress AndroidUnknownAttribute -->
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"


    android:Button=

    android:ignore="ExtraText"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">
    android:id="@+id/buttonSayHello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Say Hello"
    android:onClick="SayHello"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    > </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>



main.java
package com.example.gamin;



import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher {
    EditText nameText;
    TextView textGreeting;
    Button buttonSayHello;

    MainActivity() {
        nameText = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName);
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textGreeting = findViewById(R.textView2);
        buttonSayHello = findViewById(R.id.button);
        nameText.addTextChangedListener(this);
        buttonSayHello.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        buttonSayHello.setEnabled(!nameText.getText().toString().matches(""));
    }
    public void SayHello(View view)
    {
        if(!nameText.getText().toString().matches(""))
        {
            textGreeting.setText("Howdy "+nameText.getText());
        }
        else
        {
            textGreeting.setText("Please enter your name");
        }
    }

}

Execution failed for task ':app:parseDebugLocalResources'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable
Failed to parse XML file '/Users/gain/AndroidStudioProjects/Gamin/app/build/intermediates/packaged_res/debug/packageDebugResources/layout/activity_main.xml'

Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.ParseLibraryResourcesTask$ParseResourcesRunnable

Have you tried to validate your layout XML? e.g. android:Button= ...
